# MySQL: Get Counts and Averages

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

```
select 
COUNT(pd.property_id) AS `Beginning Total File Count`,
COUNT(pd.recv_dt) as `average days in inventory`,
AVG(pd.status = 'P') as `average days in pre-marketing`,
AVG(pd.status NOT IN('I','C')) as `average days onMarket`,
AVG(pd.status ='U') as `average days UnderContract`,
SUM(pd.status = 'O') as `Total FilesOccupied Status`,
SUM(pd.status = 'O') / COUNT(pd.property_id) as `percentage of Occupied / 
total file count`
from resnet.property_Details pd
```

I'm trying to get

1. Beginning total file count
2. Average days in inventory
3. Average days in Pre-Marketing
4. Average days on market
5. Average days under contract
6. Total files in occupied status
7. Percentage of Occupied / total file count

Not sure if my query is written properly, please help :)

[image]

Comment: how can we know the calculations with out any explanation?

Comment: What kind of explanation? Was just looking for a logic and query write check.

Comment: SO is not a query checking website.

Comment: AVG and SUM work on numeric values, not logical. As @vkp says, SO isn't a code writing service, or a query checking site. What you are looking for isn't simple, and your code is so far off, it isn't even a starting point. To get help here, you need to show that you've done the research and tried to get it working. Lookup "how to ask a question" on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok as a really wild guess, you're after this request :

```
select 
COUNT(distinct pd.property_id) AS `Beginning Total File Count`,
COUNT(pd.recv_dt) as `average days in inventory`,
AVG(IF(pd.status = 'P', 1,0)) as `average days in pre-marketing`,
AVG(IF(pd.status NOT IN('I','C'), 1,0)) as `average days onMarket`,
AVG(IF(pd.status ='U', 1,0)) as `average days UnderContract`,
SUM(IF(pd.status = 'O', 1,0)) as `Total FilesOccupied Status`,
SUM(IF(pd.status = 'O', 1,0)) / COUNT(pd.property_id) as `percentage of Occupied / 
total file count`
from resnet.property_Details pd
```

But it seem strange to use `AVG()` if you're not using a `group by` statement... ( it's either just a conditional sum or you need to group by something)